# ui-grid: How do I set column width when using pdf export

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, pdfmake

How can I set column widths when exporting pdf using ui-grid. Pdfmake has width as an option however the ui-grid exporter api docs don't have this option anywhere.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit more fiddling with the source code, discovered that the width is retrieved from the gridoptions.columnsDef.width value. Here is the link to the docs http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef